# Display Menu item "Note description" in frontend Joomla 2.5

Tags: overriding, joomla2.5, menuitem

I'm working with Joomla 2.5, every menu item has got a "Note" field that normally is used just only as a description in the back end, it's possible to display that content on the frontend of my site? the best is to display it via the override...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the "Note" field by using menu Item id

```
$menuitemid = JRequest::getInt('Itemid');
$db     =& JFactory::getDBO();  
$query = "SELECT note FROM #__menu WHERE published = 1 and id = '".$menuitemid."' ";
$db->setQuery($query);
$note = $db->loadResult();
```